# Blender how to show in outliner only the objects that are on the layer selected in the layers box?

Tags: outliner

Another way to ask this is how to show only one layer at a time in the outliner?

Answer (score 6):

By selecting "Visible Layers" from the drop down menu at the top of the outliner, and selecting the layer(s) you want to see in the outliner.

[image]